# Can Raspberry pi be configured as WIFI ap as well as client simultaneously?

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi

I would like to know if it is possible to configure Raspberry pi to work as Wifi AP and client simultaneously. I googled and found the following link

[Link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=138730)

This link is not clear but it makes a reference to this [Link-2](https://makezine.com/2016/02/28/eben-upton-talks-about-the-new-raspberry-pi-3/)

Link-2 has something mentioned like this: `It seems likely, given the chipset, that the Raspberry Pi should be able to operate in both Access Point mode and client mode simultaneously. In other words, it can get its internet connection by joining on a wireless network, while simultaneously providing a second network as an access point to a ‘cloud’ of sensors.` Which is what i'am looking for. I tried googling more, but could find setting up Raspberry pi as a Wifi AP only but not both simultaneously.

My question is: Is it really possible to set up Raspberry pi in with such a configuration mentioned in link-2. And if so can someone please tell me step-by-step to do it.

I have Raspberry Pi 3B with Raspbian Stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple wifi services with single wifi-interface(built in interface).This is common to all devices not only raspberry pi.

What you could do is to have a separate USB wifi interface(adapter) for that.There are good external USB wifi adapters to purchase in very cheap prices as well.
Try one...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The said web page was a bit confusing to me. What you pointed was the same thing i had in my mind before going through that article.

Comment: It is not impossible. Please have a look at this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328245/263453). You have to be on the same WiFi channel (Station and AP in your case) and the sw drivers need to support several modes in parallel.